# GNAT GPS Could not determine target to build

Tags: ada, gnat-gps

I'm struggling with a custom project file that will build and execute, but I get this set of warnings (or errors, I'm not sure). After a *Clean All* and then when I click the *Build -> Project -> Build All* to bring up the *Build All* dialog box:

```
[2015-01-22 23:30:39] Could not determine the target to build.
[2015-01-22 23:30:39] Could not expand argument in command line: %T
[2015-01-22 23:30:39] Build command not launched.
```

These show up (in red text) in the Messages window before I click Execute to begin the build. When I click Execute, the build completes successfully and the program runs.

The Build All dialog has this in the options dialog:

> %builder %eL -P%PP %X -k -s -d

What does this mean and why is it doing this?

If it would help, here is the project file:

```
  project LogBuffer01 is

  for Source_Dirs use ("src", "src\utilities");
  for Object_Dir use "obj";
  for Exec_Dir use "exe";
  for Main use ("abt_log_buffer_main_b.ada");

  package Naming is
     for Spec_Suffix ("ada") use "_s.ada";
     for Body_Suffix ("ada") use "_b.ada";
     for Spec ("abt_mirror_specs") use "abt_mirror_specs_s.ada";
     for Spec ("abt_log_buffer_types") use "abt_log_buffer_types_s.ada";
     for Spec ("abt_log_buffer") use "abt_log_buffer_s.ada";
     for Body ("abt_log_buffer") use "abt_log_buffer_b.ada";
     for Spec ("abt_log_buffer_rom_acess") use "abt_log_buffer_rom_access_s.ada";
     for Body ("abt_log_buffer_rom_acess") use "abt_log_buffer_rom_access_b.ada";
     for Spec ("screen_output") use "screen_output_s.ada";
     for Body ("screen_output") use "screen_output_b.ada";
  end Naming;

  package Pretty_Printer is
     for Default_Switches ("ada") use ("-i5");
  end Pretty_Printer;

  package Compiler is
        for Default_Switches ("ada") use ("-gnat83");
  end Compiler;

  package Builder is
     for Default_Switches ("ada") use ("");
  end Builder;

  package Check is
     for Default_Switches ("ada") use ("-d");
  end Check;

  end LogBuffer01;
```

Comment: Not sure about your empty string in Builder.Default_Switches. And do you need to have those Spec and Body definitions as well as Spec_Suffix, Body_Suffix? I guess that %T would be substituted by --target=arch-vendor-os if you had specified it, but why GPS wants to I don’t know. Obviously the command-line builder is happy! Which version of GPS? which OS? (I guess Windows).

Answer (score 0):

The meanings for the builder are defined [here](http://docs.adacore.com/gps-docs/users_guide/_build/html/extending.html#macro-arguments).  There's no point in me translating your command string, suffice to say that %builder translates to gnatmake because you only compile Ada.  gnatmake's switches are described  [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_ugn/Switches-for-gnatmake.html).

BTW, I have this for package Builder:

```
for Default_Switches ("ada") use ("-g", "-C", "-s");
```

but in another properly-working project I have

```
for Default_Switches ("ada") use ();
```